# Extracting cities from string vector in R

Tags: r, geocoding

I have a column in my dataset db, say db$affiliation, which looks like:

```
**db$affiliation**
[1] "[SCOTT, ALLEN J.] UNIV CALIF LOS ANGELES, DEPT GEOG, LOS ANGELES, CA 90095 USA"                               
[2] "[VAN DUINEN, RIANNE; VAN DER VEEN, ANNE] UNIV TWENTE, DEPT WATER ENGN & MANAGEMENT, DRIENERLOLAAN 5,POB 217, NL-7500 AE ENSCHEDE, NETHERLANDS."                                                
[3] "[ANANTSUKSOMSRI, SUTEE] CHULALONGKORN UNIV, FAC ARCHITECTURE, BANGKOK, THAILAND."   
[4] ...
```

I would like to create a column within the same dataset containing only the name of the city in db$affiliation, such as

```
 **db$cities**
 [1] LOS ANGELES
 [2] TWENTE
 [3] BANGKOK
 [4] ...
```

If multiple city names are available, I'd like the command to return only the last one, if no city names are available I'd like to have NA. How can I do that?

I thought that I could use `world.cities$name` in `data(world.cities)` in the `maps` package but I can not figure out how.

I even tried to split the db$affiliation column such as:

```
db$affiliation <- gsub("\\[[^\\]]*\\]", "", db$affiliation, perl=TRUE) # remove content within brackets 
db$affiliation[2] # check the separator
db <- cSplit(db, 'affiliation', sep=c(", "), type.convert=FALSE) # split after comma
```

Which results (I've truncated it after affiliation_3) in:

```
    affiliation_1            affiliation_2                  affiliation_3 
[1] UNIV CALIF LOS ANGELES   DEPT GEOG                      LOS ANGELES  
[2] UNIV TWENTE              DEPT WATER ENGN & MANAGEMENT   DRIENERLOLAAN            
[3] CHULALONGKORN UNIV       FAC ARCHITECTURE               BANGKOK
```

And then pass:

```
db$cities <- lapply(db$affiliation_1, function(x)x[which(x %in% world.cities$name)])
```

But I get an empty column.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Allen is a city in Texas. I know it is used as a name.  This kind of city names will make your work hard. Enschede exists in the Netherlands. So I am not sure if twente is the last one. I think you would need to write some codes to have good accuracy to extract city names.

Comment: You are right, that's why I've decided to split the vector into several vectors, so I could pass the matching argument to different vector manually so it would be easier to handle ambiguous results

Comment: I guess the question is to what extent do you wanna receive a help from SO users? It seems obvious to me that nobody has time to handle all jobs for you.

Comment: I just wonder if you have names in `[]`. If this is the case, you can certainly remove texts in square brackets. That will allow you to have a bit easier time, I think.

Comment: I found that `Sutee Anantsuksomsri` does exsit in a university in Thailand. So I think you are likely to have personal names in `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many cities in your sample string so you may need to think again if you still want to fetch the 'last city' in case multiple cities are found in `affiliation` column.

```r
library(maps)
data(world.cities)

#sample data
df <- data.frame(affiliation = c("[SCOTT, ALLEN J.] UNIV CALIF LOS ANGELES, DEPT GEOG, LOS ANGELES, CA 90095 USA",
                                 "[VAN DUINEN, RIANNE; VAN DER VEEN, ANNE] UNIV TWENTE, DEPT WATER ENGN & MANAGEMENT, DRIENERLOLAAN 5,POB 217, NL-7500 AE ENSCHEDE, NETHERLANDS.",
                                 "[ANANTSUKSOMSRI, SUTEE] CHULALONGKORN UNIV, FAC ARCHITECTURE, BANGKOK, THAILAND.",
                                 "Prem"), stringsAsFactors = F)

#fetch city and it's respective country from 'affiliation' column
cities_country <- lapply(gsub("\\[|\\]|[,;]|\\.","",df$affiliation), function(x) 
  paste(as.character(world.cities$name[sapply(world.cities$name, grepl, x, ignore.case=T)]),
        as.character(world.cities$country.etc[sapply(world.cities$name, grepl, x, ignore.case=T)]),
        sep="_"))
df$cities_country <- lapply(cities_country, function(x) if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x)
df
```

Output is:

```
affiliation
1                                                                 [SCOTT, ALLEN J.] UNIV CALIF LOS ANGELES, DEPT GEOG, LOS ANGELES, CA 90095 USA
2 [VAN DUINEN, RIANNE; VAN DER VEEN, ANNE] UNIV TWENTE, DEPT WATER ENGN & MANAGEMENT, DRIENERLOLAAN 5,POB 217, NL-7500 AE ENSCHEDE, NETHERLANDS.
3                                                               [ANANTSUKSOMSRI, SUTEE] CHULALONGKORN UNIV, FAC ARCHITECTURE, BANGKOK, THAILAND.
4                                                                                                                                           Prem
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            cities_country
1                                                                      Al_Norway, Alle_Switzerland, Allen_Philippines, Allen_USA, Angeles_Costa Rica, Angeles_Philippines, Cali_Colombia, Cot_Costa Rica, Li_Norway, Los Angeles_Chile, Los Angeles_USA, Os_Kyrgyzstan, Os_Norway, U_Micronesia, Usa_Japan
2 Ae_Marshall Islands, Ede_Netherlands, Ede_Nigeria, Enschede_Netherlands, Hede_China, Ine_Marshall Islands, Laa_Austria, Lola_Guinea, Man_Ivory Coast, Mana_French Guiana, Manage_Belgium, Nagem_Luxembourg, Ob_Russia, Ola_Panama, Po_Burkina Faso, U_Micronesia, Van_Turkey, Wa_Ghana, We_New Caledonia
3                                                                                                                                     Aila_Estonia, Al_Norway, Anan_Japan, Ba_Fiji, Bangkok_Thailand, Hit_Iraq, Ila_Nigeria, Ilan_Taiwan, Long_Thailand, Nan_Thailand, Tsu_Japan, U_Micronesia, Ula_Turkey
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       NA
```

(**Note** that in above output I have kept all occurrences of cities and for convenience also suffixed it with their respective countries)

Comment: Building on your answer, what I realized is that I had to find a pattern because extracting cities from the whole string was _not convenient_. I hence realized that the name of the city was usually contained in the 2nd or 3rd sub-string separated by commas starting from the end of the string. With `stringi::stri_reverse` I reversed the string, splitted it with `splitstackshape::cSplit` after each comma and passed the code you brilliantly provided only to the two columns containing the city names.

Answer (score 1):

From the few lines you have shown it looks like you might be able to do the following (note you missed aligning the casing):

```
tmpVec <- sapply(strsplit(db$affiliation, split = ","), function(x) {
  cleanVec <- toupper(trimws(x))
  cleanVec[max(which(cleanVec %in% toupper(maps::world.cities$name)))]
})
```

Or put a bit more code into the function to avoid the ugly warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this returns me just a numeric vector with few NAs and few numbers ranging from 2 to 5

Comment: Of course you are right, sorry, extraction missing there. I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Let me leave a part of a solution. As far as I can tell from my own research, letters in the square brackets seem to indicate personal names. For example, I found that `Sutee Anantsuksomsri` is an actual name. This observation suggests that we probably want to remove texts in the brackets.

Once I removed the texts in the square brackets, I split the words using `unnest_tokens()` in the tidytext package. Note that the function converts all letters to small letters. If you do not like it, you can change that by specifying `to_lower = FALSE`. First, I split each city name into word. I also assigned an ID number for each city. Second, I cleaned up your data. As I said earlier, I removed texts in square brackets using `gsub()`. Then, I applied `unnest_tokens()` to the data. I subset words using the words from `cities` in `filter()`. The result we get up to this point is the following. Obviously, you have more work to do. I leave the sampling data, `mydf` below. I hope you can move on from here.

```
data(world.cities)

cities <- world.cities %>%
          mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
          unnest_tokens(input = name, output = word, token = "words")

temp <- mydf %>%
        mutate(affiliation = gsub(x = affiliation, pattern = "\\[.*\\]", replacement = "")) %>%          
        unnest_tokens(input = affiliation, output = word, token = "words") %>%
        filter(word %in% cities$word)


   id     word
1   1      los
2   1  angeles
3   1      los
4   1  angeles
5   1       ca
6   1      usa
7   2    water
8   2       ae
9   2 enschede
10  3  bangkok
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = 1:3, affiliation = c("[SCOTT, ALLEN J.] UNIV CALIF LOS ANGELES, DEPT GEOG, LOS ANGELES, CA 90095 USA", 
"[VAN DUINEN, RIANNE; VAN DER VEEN, ANNE] UNIV TWENTE, DEPT WATER ENGN & MANAGEMENT, DRIENERLOLAAN 5,POB 217, NL-7500 AE ENSCHEDE, NETHERLANDS.", 
"[ANANTSUKSOMSRI, SUTEE] CHULALONGKORN UNIV, FAC ARCHITECTURE, BANGKOK, THAILAND."
)), .Names = c("id", "affiliation"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```